# Create firewall exception on Google Compute Engine and connect via telnet

Tags: google-compute-engine, firewall, telnet

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/linux-gui-on-the-google-cloud-platform-800719ab27c5). You do not have to read whole tutorial, my small goal is to create firewall rule on Google Compute engine and connect to using telnet.

I did create firewall rule:

[image: firewall rule]

But when type `telnet X.X.X.X 5901`, I get back

```
Connecting To X.X.X.X...Could not open connection to the host, on port 5901: Connect failed
```

I replaced actual ip with X.X.X.X in the above.

Any suggestions how I can troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work!

I suspect vncserver isn't running (correctly) on the instance.
Or you're using the internal IP rather than the external IP address.

Did you confirm the server is running before you tried access it remotely? The tutorial suggests:

```
nc localhost 5901
```

But, you could also try:

```
ss --tcp --listening | grep 5901
```

and should see something similar to

```
LISTEN     0      5          *:5901
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to tag the one `GCE` instance with `vnc-server`, in order to apply the rule. setting IP ranges to the home network might be tighter than permitting range `0.0.0.0`. think one can use [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/) to log whenever a firewall rule applies. the host firewall might also prevent the access (eg. when Stackdriver logs, but it still not works).